# How to sort data by using loops?

Tags: r, algorithm, loops, sorting, vector

I want to write a function that rearranges a vector in ascending or descending order. I know I can use sort and order functions but I want to do it manually.

Comment: Depending on which sorting algorithm you want to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: Yes it is the shortest way but is there another long way that I can write a function by using loops?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is unfortunately not really a question. You want to do this, but we don't know why, what you already achieved or even why you want to do this with R and not another language. Also, did you take a look at `View(sort.int)`?

Comment: @DanChaltiel Hi, because I am trying to write some basic functions that already in the R on my own. I started to learn R just a few months ago.

Comment: @elsa see my answer which gives a customized sort function

Comment: You should take a look at other good questions on StackOverflow and try to mimic them. Your question is unfortunately too broad. If you try to implement a function and you are stuck somewhere, you can describe your problem and others can help. But noone can help you with this type of question. Also, if you are trying to learn R and progress, I doubt this would be really helpful. There are a lot of wonderful tutorials like https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html that will help you more than that.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Yes, it is exactly what I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you are happy with my solution, feel free to upvote/accept

Answer (score 1):

If you want to practice writing your own sorting function, here is a example which applies a ***recursion approach***:

```
mysort <- function(v, descending = F) {
  if (length(v)==1) return(v)
  if (descending) return(c(max(v),mysort(v[-which.max(v)],descending = descending))) 
  return(c(min(v),mysort(v[-which.min(v)])))
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
v <- c(1,2,5,4,2,7)
# ascending manner
mysort(v)
# descending manner
mysort(v,descending = T)
```

such that

```
> mysort(v)
[1] 1 2 2 4 5 7

> mysort(v,descending = T)
[1] 7 5 4 2 2 1
```